# How to increase/decrease the temperature of white balance in AVCaptureDevice

Tags: ios, app-store, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

In my application, I'm capturing image with the help of AVFoundation library. In this, I need to set the white balancing for my photo capture.

Earlier I have followed this [link](https://github.com/brettonw/iOS-ManualCamera) , and it worked fine. But Apple rejected the binary due to non-public API usage. They already described this binary rejection issue in their documentation. This code reference will clearly describe the issue.

```
Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil)
    {
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported: AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance])
        {
            if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil])
            {
                [device setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance];
                [device setWhiteBalanceTemperature:[(UISlider *)sender value]]; // here whiteBalanceTemperature  is private API.

                [device unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone provide the alternative solution to set the temperature for white balance in AVCaptureDevice?